# Segmentation fault while moving value to stack pointer

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, stack, low-level

I get a segmentation fault in two places first when assign value to address at

```
mov [ebx] , eax
```

and when I try to push register on stack after a move value to stack pointer at

```
lea esp, [ebx+eax*2]

push eax
```

Why it happen ?

full code:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

mov eax, 0x7FFFF 
mov ebx, 0x100000
mov [ebx] , eax
mov ecx, eax
inc eax
lea esp, [ebx+eax*2]
push eax
push ecx
xor ecx, [esp +4] 
shl ecx, 12
add ecx, 0x1000
dec ecx
xchg ecx, [esp]
xor eax, eax

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission from the OS to write to the memory pages that you have pointed the stack to? Why have you altered ESP? I assume this is under Linux or some other OS?

Comment: i wanted make small training with assigning values in assembly to see how stack change it values and value registers store

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am using SASM IDE on Windows

Comment: You can't change the stack pointer to an arbitrary value and then read/write to the stack unless you have somehow allocated  the memory in question with read/write privileges.

Comment: If you want to see how the stack works, then push and pop values and see how esp changes. You can‘t just set the stack pointer to some arbitrary value.

Comment: @MichaelPetch so there is nothing I can do about it? On my final exams, I am getting such tasks to write a value of the registers or address  and I would like to somehow check the answer and  make some training to get prepared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to do

```
lea   eax, [ebx+eax*2]     ; eax = ebx + eax * 2
push  eax                  ; then push that on the stack
```

But you accidentally used `esp` as the destination for LEA, using your integer as the new stack pointer, so it's not a valid address when you try to `push` something.

`push eax` is like `sub esp,4` / `mov [esp], eax` (but without writing FLAGS), so ESP must be pointing to valid memory.  If `ebx` was a valid pointer, and `eax` an integer index, then it might make sense to calculate an offset into a buffer to use as a stack pointer, but there's no reason to expect `0x100000 + 2 * 0x8000 = 0x110000` to be a valid pointer, i.e. to mapped memory.

You don't make any `mmap` or `VirtualAlloc` system calls, so the only mapped pages are what the OS's program loader maps for you; just the pages holding your code and data.

---

Or maybe you were trying to do this on purpose, based on using `mov [0x100000] , eax`.  This of course fails for the same reason that this fails in C:

```
int *p = (int*)0x100000;
*p = 0x7FFFF;
```

**You can't just make up pointer values in code running under an OS with memory protection.**

Use a debugger or other tools to examine your process's memory map if you want.